# Does WPF Event queue in Dispatcher list?

Tags: wpf, events, dispatcher

I have read about this: "The UI thread queues work items inside an object called a Dispatcher. The Dispatcher selects work items on a priority basis and runs each one to completion." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/threading-model?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Does work items include control events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the control events, such as for example `Button.Clicked`, are raised synchronously on the UI/dispatcher thread.

Comment: It's raised on the UI/Dispatcher thread, but Is it queue in Dispatcher (and then run later when other work item in Dispatcher item list completed) or run immediately ?

Comment: Immediately assuming the UI thread isn't busy processing any queued work items.